# Server-to-multiple-client system timer to keep track of messages

Tags: c++, time, timer, client-server

I have a multiple-client-to-server system, where messages sent from *client x* is processed b the server before finally being sent onto its destination *client y*. This processing involves pushing messages into global queues and between different threads (e.g. when the message needs to travel between different nodes before being delivered). I need to collect information about the latency between *client x* sending a message and *client y* receiving it.

I would like to find out what the common way of doing this is (I have no experience in timers and will like to learn) and I have come to two hypotheses:

1. Time-stamp the messages when the server receives a message from *client x*, and then subtract that from the time when the message is finally received by the desired client
2. Start a timer for each message that arrives (this can span for '00 to '000s of messages, and I have a feeling is too processor heavy).

I need the timer to be as light-weight as possible (and I'm looking at *ms* accuracy) because there are '0-'00s clients, and the centralised server system means there could be a huge bottleneck. I appreciate any advice!